# Upload annotation into Dynamics 365 using Kingswaysoft

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I read a list of zip files, each one of them have one pdf file inside. For this  reading I use a script component in a SSIS package. Once I read the pdf file I want to save a binary version of it in a sql server table. The column that stores the documentbody is VARBINARY(MAX) type.

This is the code I use for the reading an encoding part:

```
        {
            using (ZipArchive Archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(Row.documentpath))

                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry Entry in Archive.Entries)
                 {


                    if (Path.GetExtension(Entry.Name) = "pdf")

                         {


                        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Entry.Open()))

                            FullFile = r.ReadToEnd();
                            byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FullFile);
```

Next I have a Kingswaysoft component that reads this table, where each row is a different file, and load them into Dynamics.

Everything goes without errors but when I go and check the annotation entity, I open the pdf file and it's empty, blank pages inside.

I believe it is something related with the encoding part. 
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we suggest using our [SSIS Productivity Pack](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/download) instead of the script component. With the [Compression Task](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/compression), you can decompress the files, then use our [Premium File System Source Component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/premiumfilesystem) to read the extracted PDF files and write them to the annotation entity using our [CRM Destination Component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/dynamics365).

If you require any further assistance, do not hesitate to reach out to our support team.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting empty pdf attachments when trying to create "activitymimeattachment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969510/getting-empty-pdf-attachments-when-trying-to-create-activitymimeattachment)

I found a solution through this post:

I changed the typo of the `arr` variables to `var`. I really don't know why it didn't work before, but now it does.